# How to compare two dataframes and add a new column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two datafrmaes df1, df2 described below

df1

| LOT | SLOT | EVENT_TIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2024-01-20 13:30 |
| A | 2 | 2024-01-20 13:36 |
| A | 3 | 2024-01-21 14:28 |
| A | 4 | 2024-01-21 14:30 |
| A | 5 | 2024-01-21 14:32 |
| A | 6 | 2024-01-21 14:34 |

df2

| LOT | IN_TIME | OUT_TIME | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2024-01-20 13:20 | 2024-01-20 13:40 | 13 |
| A | 2024-01-21 14:25 | 2024-01-21 14:50 | 15 |

The target dataframe should look like this:

| LOT | SLOT | EVENT_TIME | DATA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2024-01-20 13:30 | 13 |
| A | 2 | 2024-01-20 13:36 | 13 |
| A | 3 | 2024-01-21 14:28 | 15 |
| A | 4 | 2024-01-21 14:30 | 15 |
| A | 5 | 2024-01-21 14:32 | 15 |
| A | 6 | 2024-01-21 14:34 | 15 |

What I want to do is that if the LOT of df1 and df2 match and the EVENT_TIME of df1 LOT is between the IN_TIME and OUT_TIME of df2, I want to make the corresponding VALUE a new COLUMN(DATA).
( df1['LOT'] == df1['LOT'] AND df2['IN_TIME'] <= df1['EVENT_TIME'] <= df2['OUT_TIME'])

So, I tried to use a for loop as shown below,

```py
DATA = pd.Series()
for idx_1, ser_1 in df1.iterrows():
    for idx_2, ser_2 in df2.iterrows():
        if (df1['LOT'] == df2['LOT'] ) and (df1['EVENT_TIME'] >= df2['IN_TIME']) and (df1['EVENT_TIME'] <= df2['OUT_TIME']):
            DATA[idx_1] = df2['VALUE']

df = pd.concat([df1, DATA],axis=1)
```

but the number of rows in df1 and df2 exceeds 100,000, so it takes more than 10 minutes.

This is my second question, so please understand if I wasn't able to convey the meaning well. I'm always happy to help. thank you

Is there any way to optimize code other than for-loop?(ex: join, apply, map)

This is my second question, so please understand if I wasn't able to convey the meaning well. I'm always happy to help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Code**

at first make dtype to datetime

```
df1['EVENT_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['EVENT_TIME'])
df2['IN_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['IN_TIME'])
df2['OUT_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['OUT_TIME'])
```

use `merge_asof`

```
out = (
    pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, by='LOT', left_on='EVENT_TIME', right_on='IN_TIME')
    .assign(VALUE=lambda x: x['VALUE'].where(x['OUT_TIME'] >= x['EVENT_TIME']))
    .drop(['IN_TIME', 'OUT_TIME'], axis=1)
)
```

out:

```
    LOT SLOT    EVENT_TIME          VALUE
0   A   1       2024-01-20 13:30:00 13
1   A   2       2024-01-20 13:36:00 13
2   A   3       2024-01-21 14:28:00 15
3   A   4       2024-01-21 14:30:00 15
4   A   5       2024-01-21 14:32:00 15
5   A   6       2024-01-21 14:34:00 15
```

---

**Example Code**

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'LOT': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], 
         'SLOT': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
         'EVENT_TIME': ['2024-01-20 13:30', '2024-01-20 13:36','2024-01-21 14:28', '2024-01-21 14:30', '2024-01-21 14:32','2024-01-21 14:34']}

data2 = {'LOT': ['A', 'A'],
         'IN_TIME': ['2024-01-20 13:20', '2024-01-21 14:25'],
         'OUT_TIME': ['2024-01-20 13:40', '2024-01-21 14:50'],
         'VALUE': [13, 15]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```